# Remove duplicate post variation in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce, duplicates, product-variations

Need a query to remove duplicate post variation like this situation, in all products:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question lacks information to get any help from [so] users. Please take the [tour], and read through the [help], learn  [ask] a good question? to maximize your chance to get answer to your questions. If you run into a specific problem and if you're stuck, send a description of the problem, including a [mcve] and people will be very glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just load the product edit page by adding this code into the `functions.php` file of your active theme, then remove the code. Please change the product ID in the code below.

```
<?php if (isset( $_GET['post'])) {
    
$current_list = array();
$args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 500,
        'post_type' => 'product_variation',
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'asc',
        'offset' => 0,
        'ID' => 1631819251, //Parent ID
      );
      $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
      
      if ($the_query->have_posts()) {
      while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
        $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_title(); ?><br>
        <?php $this_variation_title = get_the_title();
              if (in_array($this_variation_title, $current_list)) {
                 echo $this_variation_title.' duplicate deleted.<br>';
                 wp_delete_post(get_the_ID());
              } else {
                  array_push($current_list, $this_variation_title);
                  echo 'Variation added to array.<br>';
              } ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php } ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata();
} ?>
```